# p:datatable Column's Header

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using a Datatable from the Primefaces framework and I want to change the color of the column headers. 
I tried skinning in CSS like this but it does not work:

```
.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-header {
    color: gray;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)